# Alternative to C++ FW4SPL Framework in Python

Tags: python, c++, image-processing, frameworks, augmented-reality

https://github.com/fw4spl-org/fw4spl

FW4SPL has been specifically designed for the development of computer-assisted surgical software. It is a framework for fast and easy creation of applications, mainly in the medical imaging field. It includes various features such as 2D and 3D digital image processing, visualization, augmented reality and medical interaction simulation. FW4SPL comes with VRRender, a medical image and segmentation viewer. It supports many formats including DICOM, vtk, inr, etc.

The fact that I don't know C++ makes it difficult for me to use this framework. Are there any alternative frameworks that are supported in Python that can do similar things?